# I'm having issue while formatting data from a list in python2.7 and appending it to another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
users = ["<USER John Bells (100000469012345)>","<USER Shaym kismet (1027112345)>"]
unsorted_list = []
username_list = []
users_id_list = []

def data_handeling01():
    for friends_list in users:
        unsorted_list.append(friends_list)

    print unsorted_list
    for data in unsorted_list:
        string01 = data[6::]
        splitted_info = string01.split(" (")
        username_list.append(str(splitted_info[0]))
        users_id_list.append(splitted_info[-1].split(")")[0])

        print username_list
        print users_id_list
data_handeling01()
```

**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-formatted-data-lists.py", line 19, in <module>
    data_handeling01()
  File "get-formatted-data-lists.py", line 12, in data_handeling01
    string01 = data.data[6::]
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'data'
```

**

***The Results I'm looking for is that usernames to go in username_list =["John Bells"] and the user id to go in users_id_list = ["100000469012345"]***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
import re
users = ["<USER John Bells (100000469012345)>","<USER Shaym kismet (1027112345)>"]
username_list = []
users_id_list = []

for i in users:
    m = re.search("\<USER\s+(.*?)\((.*?)\)", i)
    if m:
        username_list.append(m.group(1))
        users_id_list.append(m.group(2))
print(username_list)
print(users_id_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['John Bells ', 'Shaym kismet ']
['100000469012345', '1027112345']
```

Answer (score 0):

For me your code is working a even simplify a bit:

```
users = ["<USER John Bells (100000469012345)>","<USER Shaym kismet (1027112345)>"]
unsorted_list = []
username_list = []
users_id_list = []

def data_handeling01():
    for data in users:
        string01 = data[6::]
        splitted_info = string01.split(" (")
        username_list.append(str(splitted_info[0]))
        users_id_list.append(splitted_info[-1].split(")")[0])

    print username_list
    print users_id_list
data_handeling01()
```

this is the result:

```
['John Bells', 'Shaym kismet'] 
['100000469012345', '1027112345']
```

Comment: Every thing looks good, this is the output 
`['John Bells', 'Shaym kismet']`
`['100000469012345', '1027112345']`